# grep for a string from URLs of different lengths

Tags: bash, grep

I have a text file (foo.txt) containing a number of URLs.  Each URL contains a file ID:

```
www.url.com/etc/one/two/72f66_59875c1ffb57b5992-b18/something/maybe/
www.url.com/etc/8823cd1-ab9532a5dc74cc904cc6bd3e2/perhaps/
www.url.com/etc/something/8407fb_80bbb9c0d/1/2/6/
```

My expected output is just the file IDs:

```
72f66_59875c1ffb57b5992-b18
8823cd1-ab9532a5dc74cc904cc6bd3e2
8407fb_80bbb9c0d
```

I don't yet completely understand how to leverage grep to make this happen.  I have been humbled.

Comment: How do you recognize the file id from the rest of it.   As far as I can tell it isn't the part just after /etc and it isn't the same distance from the end either.  Maybe it's the only part that has an _ or a hyphen?

Comment: it might be easier to use sed or awk.  Do you need to use grep?

Comment: Good observation.  The file ID is the long string that begins with a number.  Sometimes it contains an underscore, sometimes a hyphen, sometimes both or sometimes neither.  As far as I've been able to tell, the length of the ID is 15+ characters long.

Comment: I do not need to use grep, no.  It was the first method that came to mind.  I tried awk and sed as well but was just as unsuccessful.

Comment: Is it always in the middle with a slash on both sides or can it be right at the end with no trailing slash.

Comment: What version of grep do you have?

Comment: It is always within a slash on both ends of the string.

Comment: I'm using GNU grep 3.7 on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those look like all hex digits, so

```sh
grep -oE '/[[:xdigit:]_-]{15,}/' foo.txt  | tr -d /
```

Comment: Wow!  That is brilliant!  Thank you @glenn-jackman !

Comment: If you want to use only grep (without tr) then `grep -oP '(?<=/)[[:xdigit:]_-]{15,}(?=/)' foo.txt`

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you @JerryJeremiah